# Inside Directive click function add TextBox elements with different scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a directive , on click of button i need to add text box but when i add 2,3 textbox they all share same scope.

How can i isolate the scope inside directive ??

```
http://jsfiddle.net/A8Vgk/584/
```

**Code::**

```
    angular.module('myApp', []).directive( 'test', function ( $compile ) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { text: '@' },
    template: '<p ng-click="add()">Click me </p>',
    controller: function ( $scope, $element ) {
      $scope.add = function () {
        var el = $compile( "<input type='text' ng-model='user.name' value='hello-World!'>" )( $scope );
        $element.parent().append( el );
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [$scope.$new()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24new) and bind your textbox to this newly created scope:

```
var el = $compile( "<input type='text' ng-model='user.name' value='hello-World!'>" )( $scope.$new() );
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/A8Vgk/585/)